# After upgrading ArcGIS Pro getting "Failed to Initialize Python Interpreter" error

Tags: python, installation, arcgis-pro

I just upgraded ArcGIS Pro to version 2.2 from within the application. After the upgrade, when I open a project, this dialog comes up:

[image]

Also, the Python window shows this:

[image]

Finally, I cannot seem to see any toolboxes in the geoprocessing window.

[image]

Am I going to have to uninstall and reinstall to fix this? Or is there some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this if you're willing:

1. get the latest version of the pro msi
   (http://links.esri.com/pro/download/current)
2. Run the msi and choose the **repair** option

Comment: That fixed my python interpreter and my toolboxes. Thanks.

Comment: this is the knowledge base article on this problem: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018812

Answer (score 2):

I can offer no explanation as to what may have gone astray with your upgrade because mine from 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 went without a hitch.

However, with the Python window failing to initialize I think the quick fix will be to uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS Pro which should make sure that it can find Python 3.6.5 in the expected location.

I am sure that there will be other ways to fix this but the above procedure should have you up and back running in 30-60 minutes.

One of your symptoms seems to match that at [Toolboxes not appearing in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287839/toolboxes-not-appearing-in-arcgis-pro) so I am mentioning that question here in case resolving your or that question sheds any light on the other.

Comment: Using @gotchula's solution, I had it up and running properly in just a few minutes. The longest part of the process was downloading the 1.1GB file.

Comment: @Fezter as soon as I saw that second answer I was pretty sure it would work and be quicker than mine so I'm glad it got to you in time.

Answer (score 1):

If these solutions don't work, this was a simple fix: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000022262

**Clear cache**

Clear all cache files in the AppData folder, and relaunch ArcGIS Pro.

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\ESRI\Local Caches

Comment: Encountered this in 2.7.3. Solved the issue without going through a reinstall